# Computing Sum of Multiplication of Matrix Exponents

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication, exponential

I am stuck at the following problem:

For a given exponent N, a 2x2 matrix A and a limit L, recursively compute matrix S:

S = I + A + A^2 + A^3 + ... + A^N

where I is the identity matrix.

If any of the elements of matrix S are greater than or equal to L. Decrement by L until it
is lower than L.

My algorithm is as follows:

```
// Pre-condition: 
// Parameters:
// An integer indicating an exponent
// A 2d 2x2 integer array must exist as an instance attribute
// Post-condition: The matrix resulting from the sum of multiplied matrices 
// i.e. A^2 + A^1 + I
public int[][] computeMatrixSum(int exp)
{
    if(exp == 0)
    {
        return new int[][]
        {
            new int[]{ 1,0 },
            new int[]{ 0,1 }
        };
    }
    else
    {
        int[][] matrixB = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
        int[][] matrixC = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];

        matrixB = matrix;

        for(int expC = exp; expC > 1; expC--)
        {
            // Multiply the matrix
            for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < matrixB[0].length; k++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++)
                    {
                        matrixC[i][k] += matrix[i][j] * matrixB[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            matrixB = matrixC;
            matrixC = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
        }

        // Recursively calculate the sum of the other matrix products
        int[][] tmpSum = computeMatrixSum(exp-1);

        int[][] matrixSum = new int[matrixB.length][matrixB[0].length];

        for(int row = 0; row < matrixB.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < matrixB[0].length; col++)
            {
                matrixSum[row][col] = matrixB[row][col] + tmpSum[row][col];
            }
        }

        return matrixSum;
    }
}

// Pre-condition:
// Parameters: 
// An integer indicating the exponent to apply on the matrix
// An integer indicating the limit of the elements of the 2d matrix sum
// An 2d 2x2 integer array must exist as an instance attribute
// Post-condition: The matrix resulting from the sum of multiplied matrices
// that has elements that are not greater than the given limit
// i.e. A^2 + A^1 + I
public int[][] solve(int exp,int limit)
{
        int[][] matrixSum = computeMatrixSum(exp);

        for(int row = 0; row < matrixSum.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < matrixSum.length; col++)
            {
                while(matrixSum[row][col] >= limit)
                    matrixSum[row][col] -= limit;
            }
        }

        return matrixSum;
}
```

My algorithm works. But it is way too slow for large values of N. This is because I keep re-computing the result of all the exponents when I multiply them.

I do not know of any other algorithm that is more efficient in solving this problem.

Could someone please advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you apply [*Horner's method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15216775/230513)?

Comment: Wow. That's pretty complex. Especially when you have to multiply matrices rather than constants.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to apply [*Horner's method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to transform "the monomial form into a computationally efficient form," as suggested by examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216569/evaluating-a-polynomial-with-horners-algorithm-and-calculating-steps-java/15216775#15216775) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276150/single-variable-polynomial-from-text-file/8285147#8285147) for polynomials. You may be able to leverage the [`JScience`](http://jscience.org/) class [`Matrix`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/Matrix.html) to simplify the coding.

Answer (score 1):

If `A-I` is invertible, then you can find `S` exactly the same as with a geometric series, just remembering that you have to multiply by the inverse instead of dividing:

```
S = I + A + A^2 + A^3 + ... + A^N
AS = A + A^2 + A^3 + ... + A^N + A^{N+1}
AS-S = A^{N+1}-I
(A-I)S = A^{N+1}-I
S = (A-I)^{-1} (A^{N+1}-I)
```

If `N` is truly huge, then you'll want to [exponentiate by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).  Decrementing by `L` is easy, although you may want to use the modulus operator.

If `A-I` is singular, this approach won't work, and the best approach I can think of is to use the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of `A` (which will also work in the first case, if you want).